# Selenium-vba Get element by Class Name

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when I try the following I get an error "object does not support property or method"

```
Sub Testing()
   Dim driver As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
   driver.Start "chrome", "http://www.tsn.ca/fury-upsets-klitschko-to-become-heavyweight-champion-1.401257"
   driver.Open "/"

   MsgBox driver.getElementsByClassName("headline").Text

End Sub
```

I have also tried `driver.getElementsByClassName("headline")(0).Text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not "get" - it is "find":

```
driver.findElementByClassName("headline").Text
```

Alternatively, using a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElementByCssSelector(".headline").Text
```

Answer (score 0):

The headline element within the [website](https://www.tsn.ca/fury-upsets-klitschko-to-become-heavyweight-champion-1.401257) is:

```
<div class="headline">
    <h1>Fury upsets Klitschko to win heavyweight titles</h1>
</div>
```

So you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByClassName*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByClassName("headline").Text
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("div.headline > h1").Text
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='headline']/h1").Text
  ```