# SeleniumBasic - VBA - Edgedriver - FindElementsByClass doesn't work

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am trying to get the text from the tag below by doing either:

`.FindElementByClass("fFGajs").text` or,

`.FindElementsByClass("fFGajs")(1).text` (single tag on the page),

but I am getting `""`, and I can only think of the HTML Comments `<!---->` messing it up.

**What is the problem here with getting: "659 In Stock - FREE next working day delivery available" ?**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977978/selenium-vba-get-element-by-class-name

Comment: The class you are trying to find is actually `sc-fBuWsC fFGajs` which is a compound class and not supported by selenium-edgedriver.